# Solving "504 Receive Error" for every endpoint in an API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I inherited a suite of APIs based on .Net 6. Each API is in its own solution. I debug them locally by simply bringing up the solution, pressing F5, verifying they are running by looking at the Swagger page for each, and hit them via Postman. Running them locally, they're simply coming up on a random port (or sometimes, a port assigned via appsettings), and I can hit them in postman via calls to "http://localhost:[port]/endpoint_name." The APIs are being hosted in local IIS. Everything (well, at least a half dozen APIs I've tested so far) works as expected, except for one.

**ONE** of these APIs is consistently returning a cryptic "504 - Receive Failure" for any and all endpoints (there are dozens) in the API. Postman simply gives me back a cryptic "ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes."

I am not sure how to begin attacking this problem. Any and all suggestions welcome.  I am pulling out my hair.  Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Verified the API code is actually running. I can see the entire API with its endpoints in a browser window with swagger, pointed to the port on which it's running:

[image: Swagger view]

ANY call to any endpoint via Postman returns this however (sorry for the obfuscations, company policy)

[image: Postman response]

2. As I said, I have a suite of APIs I work with. I can bring up any of the others and they work perfectly. The technical details are essentially identical to the failed project--they're all .Net 6, they all expose their endpoints via controllers in the same way, they're all being hosted locally, etc. The only difference I can see is of course the port numbers.

I've tried bringing up the failing API on different ports thinking maybe there was a conflict with port numbers, but I get the same results.

For reference, here is all I see in Fiddler.

[image: fiddler view]

3. I have of course placed breakpoints in all of the controller methods that handle the various GET and PUT operations I'm trying to hit via Postman. I never reach the breakpoints.
4. None of the output from the "bad" API seems to indicate any problems. That is, the "Output" window shows the code spinning up normally with no warnings or errors. There's nothing in the Error List.
5. I've had other developers on our team run the same API using the same methods and **it works for them.**  This is what's most confusing. To ensure I'm running the same code, another developer and I both wiped the solution from our hard drives, cloned a fresh copy of the repo from Git so we're running exactly the same code. It works for him. I get the error.
6. Research on "504 Receive" error is giving me nothing. Google insists on giving me results for "504 Gateway Timeout". None of the common remedies for a 504 error seem to apply to me. I don't have a remote host that's timing out. The host is localhost. I'm "hosting" all the other APIs I mentioned as working in exactly the same way, which I think eliminates the possibility that there's something wrong with IIS locally, or that I'm having a gateway or firewall issue, etc. In short, nothing that would seem to apply for a 504 error makes sense here.

EDIT:  test-netconnection -computername localhost -port 51794
via powershell shows me my target port is open and responding

Any thoughts on what I might try next to solve this? The fact that the solution runs for others, and it's exactly the same code, would seem to indicate some type of local problem. However, given that I am able to run a ton of other solutions that are set up identically would seem to rule out common issues like gateways, firewalls, etc. Honestly, I initially thought it was going to simply be the port in question but I've tried several.

Sorry so verbose. I usually go with more information is better than less.  TIA.

Comment: Debug. Put a breakpoint in the API and see if it gets hit. Look at the output when running to look for any exceptions being thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Heretic. A mentioned, I do have breakpoints all over the place. Especially in each controller associated with the endpoints I'm trying to hit. None are hit. The requests don't seem to be making it that far.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLVED!**

So for this particular API, when it fires up, I see the following in chrome.

https://localhost:**51794**/swagger/index.html?url=/swagger/v1/swagger.json

Well, I dug into my launchSettings.json and found the following:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "NPS.Lookup.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:51794;http://localhost:51795"
    }
  }
}
```

So here was the problem:  https://localhost:51794

The "https" doesn't show in the chrome window when the app starts up, I just see the URL:

localhost:51794/swagger/index.html?url=/swagger/v1/swagger.json

I'm not set up to host anything via https in local iis, so it's no wonder I'm getting an error if I try to hit an endpoint via Postman, like:

http://localhost:51794/api/a/b/c/d/12345

A simple change to use the http endpoint specified in the launchsettings makes everything work just fine:

http://localhost:**51795**/api/a/b/c/d/12345

I think the confusion here originates with not having "https" in the swagger URL when the code fires up. I was simply taking the port number specified in the swagger endpoint and using it in my postman calls. Our standard here for development is to use the http port. For reasons I can't explain, all the other APIs I'm debugging DO fire up a swagger page with using http instead of https.  Just not this one.

Comment: The fact you're not using HTTPS for everything in 2023 is incredibly concerning.

Comment: Please see the launchsettings example I posted.  http only hosted locally on the same machine. https EVERYWHERE else. Cannot see the need to set up and enable SSL for a local project, but...